# Is there a high-performance method to copy the signature of a glm::vec?

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, glm-math

In my previous question on stack overflow, I asked about mapping coordinates to binary representations of quadtree nodes. Now, I am interested in figuring out if there is an efficient way to copy the signature of a `glm::vec` object.

As an example, given `glm::vec2 input{3,-4}`, is there an efficient way to get `glm::vec2 output{1,-1}`? The first solution that comes to mind would be to run a function:

```
glm::vec2 copySigns(glm::vec2& input) {
    if ((input.x < 0) and (input.y < 0)) {
        return {-1,-1};
    }
    if (input.x < 0) {
        output.x = -1;
    }
    if (input.y < 0) {
        output.y = -1;
    }
    // so on and so forth
}
```

But that seems extremely inefficient for what should be a simple problem, so is there a more elegant solution? One that could be used for a `glm::vec2`, `glm::vec3`, or `glm::vec4`?

Comment: Does not `glm::sign(v)` already exist which does exactly this?

Comment: @MikaelÖhman huh, I guess I'll need to make better use of the glm webpage. Thank you!